# How can I search for more than one keyword while fetching tweets using twitter streaming API in python 3.6?

Tags: datetime, twitter, python-3.6, twitter-streaming-api

How can I search for more than one keyword while fetching tweets using twitter streaming API in python 3.6?
I want to fetch old tweets from jan 01 2017 to jan 31 2017. But,using the following code, I can only fetch tweets that contain only one keyword! This is my code:

```
import got3

max_tweets = 3
tweetCriteria = got3.manager.TweetCriteria().setSince("2017-01-01").setUntil("2017-01-31").setQuerySearch("Mexico Earthquake").setMaxTweets(max_tweets)

for i in range(max_tweets):
    tweet = got3.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)[i]
    print(tweet.id)
    print(tweet.username)
    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.date)
```

In the above code, "Mexico Earthquake" is my keyword. I want to include "Magnitude 7.5" as the keyword also. I try to give a list as an argument to setQuerySearch,but it shows an error: "only str is accepted as an argument,not list" 
How can I modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't get old tweet by using twitter API because it get tweets in last week.
You hove to use search engine of twitter.
[GetOldTweets-python](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python) is a program that get old tweets with any keywords you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The above code is from https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python (GetOldTweets-python) but,in this I am able to give only one keyword to setQuerySearch. How can I give multiple keywords at a time so that I can directly search for tweets containing these keywords?

Comment: You can edit query data type to list of string and each keywords appends by OR in query. I edited him java program for list of keywords and it works.

Answer (score 0):

i found it worked best with separate query classes and set query searches.

```
text_query = ','
hashtag_query = ','
mention_query = ','

.setQuerySearch(text_query)\
.setQuerySearch(hashtag_query)\
.setQuerySearch(mention_query)\
```